# cmake doesn't add the jsoncpp generated files to the bin

Tags: cmake, jsoncpp

I used https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp and downloaded cmake, python, scons. Followed everything that was in build guide and cmake doesn't put what is generated in the bin directory, anyone have an idea?

Using windows 7 if that helps

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are very Linux-centric.  I'm guessing if you're on Windows you might be using Visual Studio, in which case the following should work (I didn't use SCONS or Python):

```
git clone git@github.com:open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G"Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64" ..\jsoncpp
cmake --build . --config Debug
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Line 4 is specifying VS 2013 as the generator targeting a 64-bit build.  To create a 32-bit build, simply omit the `Win64`.  To see all available generators, just run `cmake` with no args.

Once line 4 has completed, you should have a VS solution called "jsoncpp.sln" in the root of your build folder.  You can either open this and build from VS, or just use CMake to invoke the compiler by running lines 5 & 6.

Building the project also causes the tests to run, some of which fail.  This makes it appear that the build has failed, but in fact you should have the test exes in the bin folder (e.g. build\bin\Debug\jsoncpp_test.exe) and the library in the lib folder (e.g. build\lib\Release\jsoncpp.lib).

I'm not sure how significant the test failures are - I'd be worried if I were you :-)